# Does Ansible have the ability to suspend a Linux system?

Tags: linux, ansible

I'm having trouble locating any modules besides rebooting and shutdown for Linux. I'm wondering if anyone has done this?

Answer (score 1):

You could run a shell command through ansible.

```
- name: suspend "{{ ansible_hostname }}"
  command: systemctl suspend
```

As for waking them up again: Wake-On-LAN?